# Why i cant see a specific wireless network?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, hp-pavilion

My laptop (which is a hp pavilion g6 with broadcom 4313gn adaptor and running windows 7 enterprise sp1) sometimes can't see the wireless ssid at my work.

For ex: for a couple of days i can see and connect to it without problem, but the next day i even cant see the ssid in the list. And this contioues for days and sometimes weeks. In someday suddenly again i started to see & connect to the network. I also use wifi frequently at home (and some other places) without any problem.

This issue is just limited with this network and just me, nobody is having this issue and I'm pretty sure it is not related with my location and signal strength.

PS:I don't have direct access to the access point. I think that this must be ralated to my laptop but if needed deeply i can access it with our system admin.

Comment: Have you removed and recreated the WiFi profile for that location?  When you can't see the SSID, does moving (closer to the antenna) and refreshing (and giving it time to find it) help any?

Comment: Yes i have tried removing the profile but thst doesn't solve the issue. And also as i said before this is not related to the location. even if i go next to the access point i cant see it and when the times i see it signal strength is good.

Answer (score 1):

Steps I would take:

- Remove the profile for that network
- Add it back in (could try that for a week to see whether the issue is gone)
- Uninstall the wireless drivers and add them back on again.

Start with troubleshooting with those 3 steps first. It may fix it first time.

Also just a thought, you can also make the wireless adapter connect to the SSID even if it isn't broadcasting. May be worth while enabling that setting on the profile too.

Comment: Also try disabling/re-enabling the network adapter as well - Windows 7 wifi adapters are notorious for getting "stuck" sometimes.

Comment: Instead of reinstalling drivers, find actual version on HP site.

Comment: unfortunately removing profile and reinstalling the drivers did not help. (i download latest drivers again from hp's support). Also Disable/re-enable wifi and restart laptop did not solves the issue.

Comment: Now i try to add connection manually and selecting the option "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting its name (SSID)" but still cant connect.

Comment: Try booting into a live CD such as linux , just to identify whether this is software based or hardware.